# How to filter array of objects and assign it in new variable list in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, list

Need to retrieve records of male objects from the list.

```
list=[
{ id: 1, name: "Sam", sex: "M"},
{ id: 2, name: "Jane", sex: "F"},
{ id: 3, name: "Mark", sex: "M"},
{ id: 4, name: "Mary, sex: "F"},
{ id: 5, name: "Olivia", sex: "F"},
{ id: 6, name: "Bob", sex: "M"}
]

var maleList = ??? //male list
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

`var maleList = list.filter( x => x.sex === 'M');`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69232255/edit) your answer to add explanations.

Answer (score 0):

`var result = list.filter((x) => return x.sex == "M");`
refer to below link for more details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter